# How To Hide Adsense Java Script For Some WordPress User Roles?

Tags: php, wordpress, adsense

**My adsense auto ads should only kick in when they are not part of particular user role and normal site visitors**.

Roles with the following IDs *8396,6571,6570,6570,6569,6555,6562,6561,6560* should **not load** the javascript in the header.

I've tried a code suggested by the plugin developer.

`add_action('wp_head', 'Adsense');
function Adsense(){
  ?>
  [pms-restrict subscription_plans="8396,6571,6570,6570,6569,6555,6562,6561,6560" message="<script data-ad-client='ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX' async src='https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js'></script>"][/pms-restrict]
  <?php
};`

It's showing [pms-restrict subscription_plans="8396,6571,6570,6570,6569,6555,6562,6561,6560" message=""][/pms-restrict] on top of the website which is not good.

Comment: I'd strip down the code until you do not see the problem any more or until it's obvious where the problem lies.

Comment: @hagello clarify, thank you.